# Show another license page after finish main installation part using NSIS

Tags: installation, nsis

So, this is my current installer page structure:

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
page custom CheckHWSpecs
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${SOURCEFOLDER}\CDA_update061702.txt"
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VERIFYONLEAVE
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU Application $StartMenuGroup
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
```

When user finish installing the main application, I need to install a third-party application. Before start to install the 3rd-party app, I need to show another license page and if user agree, it will continue to install the app. But, if user disagree, it will cancel the 3rd-party app installation and the installation process is finish.

Can I do something like this?

```
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
page custom CheckHWSpecs
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${SOURCEFOLDER}\CDA_update061702.txt"
!define MUI_DIRECTORYPAGE_VERIFYONLEAVE
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_STARTMENU Application $StartMenuGroup
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${SOURCEFOLDER}\license2.txt"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_CONFIRM
!insertmacro MUI_UNPAGE_INSTFILES
```

But if there are two `!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES`, how to make sure the 3rd-party installer will run in the second MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES?

Comment: You can only have a single `MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES`

Comment: @Seki do you have any idea?

Comment: I just posted a suggestion in answer

Comment: You can have multiple MUI_PAGE_* of each type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
!include Sections.nsh
!include WinMessages.nsh
ShowInstDetails show
!include MUI2.nsh
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_WELCOME
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Examples\example1.nsi"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX
!define MUI_LICENSEPAGE_CHECKBOX_TEXT "Blah blah blah app and agree..."
!define MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_SHOW Lic2Show
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${NSISDIR}\Examples\example2.nsi"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_FINISH
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English

Section /o "Bonus app" SID_BONUS
DetailPrint "Installing bonus app..."
Sleep 2222
SectionEnd

Section "Main app" SID_MAIN
DetailPrint "Installing main app..."
Sleep 2222

!insertmacro SelectSection ${SID_BONUS}
!insertmacro UnselectSection ${SID_MAIN}
SectionEnd

Function Lic2Show
GetDlgItem $0 $hwndparent 2
SendMessage $0 ${WM_SETTEXT} 0 "STR:$(MUI_BUTTONTEXT_FINISH)"
FunctionEnd
```

If the user does not install the extra app then you never get to the finish page, the cancel button is just renamed to "Finish".

Comment: how to specify which section will be installed in the first mui_page_instfiles and which one in the 2nd page?

Comment: @currarpickt: Did you even try the example? Section /o makes the section unselected, then at the end of the main section they are both toggled...

Comment: yeah I already tried the example. But, like you mentioned before, if user does not install the extra app then it never go to finish page. Can I keep showing finish page even the 3rd party is not installed?

Comment: I write the detail of my question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734465/show-finish-page-if-user-click-cancel-on-license-page-nsis Could you take at look at my question there?

Answer (score 0):

- I would configure the 3rd -party app as another section (it can be hidden if the text is empty or by code with a `SectionSetText ${SectionID} ""`).
- After the first licence page, use a custom page to display the 2nd license with a checkbox to accept it (IIRC you can use only one `MUI_PAGE_LICENSE`)
- depending on the result of the custom page (use a custom page leave callback to test for acceptance or not), check the hidden section with `!insertmacro SelectSection ${SectionID}`
- then during the execution of `MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES` your 3rd-party app will be installed (or not) like the main app.

Comment: I want the 2nd license page shows up after main app installation process finish. After user agree with the 2nd license, then I will start to install my 3rd-party app. Is it possible to do like that?

Comment: I am afraid that you cannot do that in a single installer. Wrap your second application in another setup and start that setup from a custom page after the `MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES`